# Roboguice 2.0 testing tutorial

Tags: unit-testing, testing, roboguice

I'm using RoboGuice 2.0 but I have a hard time testing the code.
The only documentation I found, used RoboUnitTestCase which does not seem to exist in RoboGuice 2.0 anymore.
I searched a lot for a tutorial on this topic but didn't find anything.

Does anyone know a good example or tutorial for this?

Comment: Hi Marc, I'm planning on writing one. Any specific topics you are struggling with?